# Unsupported PixelFormat - SetPixelData

Tags: c#, image, bitmap, uwp, windows-10-universal

I have this function which converts the array of ushort to a grayscale image. I do the converts to convert the values to a byte-array and then use BitmapEncoder.

```
public static async Task<StorageFile> WriteableBitmapToStorageFile(ushort[,] image, bool isScaleValues, List<KeyValuePair<string, BitmapTypedValue>> metadata)
    {
        //Setup image
        var imgHeight = image.GetLength(0);
        var imgWidth = image.GetLength(1);
        float maxVal = 1;
        if (isScaleValues)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < imgHeight; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < imgWidth; j++)
                {
                    if (maxVal < image[i, j])
                    {
                        maxVal = image[i, j];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        byte[] data = new byte[imgWidth * imgHeight];
        if (image != null)
        {
            if (isScaleValues)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < imgHeight; x++)
                    for (int y = 0; y < imgWidth; y++)
                        data[x * imgWidth + y] = (byte)(((double)UInt16.MaxValue * (double)image[x, y]) / (double)maxVal);
            }
            else
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < imgHeight; x++)
                    for (int y = 0; y < imgWidth; y++)
                        data[x * imgWidth + y] = (byte)image[x, y];
            }
        }

        string FileName = "MyFile.png";
        var file =
            await
                Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder.CreateFileAsync(FileName,
                    CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
        using (IRandomAccessStream stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
        {
            BitmapEncoder encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.PngEncoderId, stream);
            encoder.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Gray16, BitmapAlphaMode.Ignore,
                (uint) imgWidth,
                (uint) imgHeight,
                2822.222222222222,
                2822.222222222222,
                data);
            await encoder.BitmapProperties.SetPropertiesAsync(metadata);
            await encoder.FlushAsync();
        }
        return file;
    }
```

I get this exception at `SetPixelData`:

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> WinRT information: Windows.Graphics.Imaging: The bitmap pixel format is unsupported.
>
> Additional information: The parameter is incorrect.
>
> Windows.Graphics.Imaging: The bitmap pixel format is unsupported.

The 2D ushort array is already 16-bit grayscale image with first dimension being the height and the 2nd being the width. Since grayscale is apparently not supported, I will need to save it as Rgba16, so the question is: How to convert grayscale to RBG?

AFAIK, I just need to set all R,G,B to the same value but how would I place the values in the array.

What is the RGBA16 format in binary?

Comment: The choice of a 16bpp grayscale pixel format seems odd. Your source data has only 8bpp resolution. Encoding it with 16bpp doesn't magically add any information. What's the rationale for that? `BitmapPixelFormat.Gray8` seems more appropriate.

Comment: Both don't work anyways. But to clarify, the array of bytes was originally a ushort array as well but I had to change it to byte cause `SetPixelData` only takes an 8bit byte. While it has option for grayscale 16.. here is where this gets really weird.

Comment: The `BitmapPixelFormat` enumeration is used in other places as well. It's not invented just for the bitmap encoder interface. At any rate, you already know that the pixel format is unsupported (from the exception description). There's little point in using it.

Comment: But I do need to have it grayscale, how can I bypass this ? Do you know any 3rd party library to do the job ?

Comment: If `BitmapPixelForm.Gray8` isn't supported either, you can simply create a grayscale image by setting all channels (RGB) to the same value for each pixel, and store it as a 24bpp RGB or 32bpp RGBA file.

Comment: 32bpp is not supported either, in fact, it doesn't even exist in the enum.
Would Rgba16 work ?

Comment: You have an odd interpretation of *"not supported"*, which makes me wonder, whether you **really** get the same exception for `Gray8`. At any rate, the [BitmapPixelFormat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.graphics.imaging.bitmappixelformat) enumeration provides 2 32bpp formats: `Rgba8` and `Bgra8`.

Comment: Yes, Gray8 gives unsupported exception, the same one.

Isn't Rgba8 8bpp ?.. This thing is starting to be really confusing...

Comment: That's why I linked to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.graphics.imaging.bitmappixelformat), which describes `Rgba8` as *"The pixel format is R8G8B8A8 unsigned integer."* That's 8 bits per 4 channels, for a grand total of 32bpp.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123895/discussion-between-ahmad45123-and-iinspectable).

Comment: How you get the ushort array? What do you want to implement? Do you want to convert a color image into a grayscale image?

Comment: I've added more details about the problem in the main post, at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have had a 2D ushort array contains 16 bpp grayscale pixels. I'd suggest you use this array to create a [**SoftwareBitmap**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.graphics.imaging.softwarebitmap.aspx) with **Gray16** pixel format first and then use [**SoftwareBitmap.Convert**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.graphics.imaging.softwarebitmap.covert.aspx) method to convert it to **Rgba16** pixel format.

[**BitmapPixelFormat.Gray16**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.graphics.imaging.bitmappixelformat.aspx) represent 16 bpp grayscale pixel format which means each pixel takes two bytes. So we need a byte array whose length is twice of the ushort array and use [**BitConverter.GetBytes(UInt16)**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8wwsdz3k(v=vs.110).aspx) method to convert `ushort` to `byte[]`. Following is a simple sample:

```
ushort[,] image = { { ushort.MinValue, ushort.MaxValue, ushort.MaxValue }, { ushort.MaxValue, ushort.MinValue, ushort.MaxValue }, { ushort.MaxValue, ushort.MaxValue, ushort.MinValue } };

var imgHeight = image.GetLength(0);
var imgWidth = image.GetLength(1);

byte[] data = new byte[image.Length * 2];

for (int i = 0; i < imgHeight; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < imgWidth; j++)
    {
        byte[] byteArray = BitConverter.GetBytes(image[i, j]);

        data[i * imgWidth * 2 + j * 2] = byteArray[0];

        data[i * imgWidth * 2 + j * 2 + 1] = byteArray[1];
    }
}

//Create a SoftwareBitmap with 16 bpp grayscale pixel format
var softwareBitmap = new SoftwareBitmap(BitmapPixelFormat.Gray16, imgWidth, imgHeight);
softwareBitmap.CopyFromBuffer(data.AsBuffer());

//Convert pixel format to Rgba16 so that we can save it to the file
softwareBitmap = SoftwareBitmap.Convert(softwareBitmap, BitmapPixelFormat.Rgba16);

var outputFile = await ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder.CreateFileAsync("MyFile.png", CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);

//Save softwareBitmap to file
using (IRandomAccessStream stream = await outputFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
{
    // Create an encoder with the desired format
    BitmapEncoder encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.PngEncoderId, stream);

    // Set the software bitmap
    encoder.SetSoftwareBitmap(softwareBitmap);

    await encoder.FlushAsync();
}
```

Comment: Just saw this now.. I used a 3rd party library.. I will see if this works, I will mark this as answer.

Comment: Hi @Ahmad45123, any update? Dose my solution work? If you still have problem, please feel free to tell me.